# Why EntityManager.find() always return null in google appengine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

I have a problem where I can't retrieve entities using their keys. I can view the entities using datastore viewer so they do exist.

I tried the following:

- Retrieving all entities using EntityManager.createQuery(), it works but I don't want to retrieve all of them.
- I tried using key.getId() and KeyFactor.keyToString(key) with EntityManager.find() still returns null.

keys are stored in another entity, I am sure they are stored correctly since I can view them and compare them in the datastore viewer.

Part of my code:

**key definition**

```
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    ...
}
```

**Function to get the entity, auto generated by google plug-in(I changed it from Long id to key to try to solve the problem):**

```
public Group getGroup(Key key) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Group group = null;
    try {
        group = mgr.find(Group.class, key);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return group;
}
```